# java if statement text prompt not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, if-statement

Very new to coding and not one of my strengths in the slightest... Initially my text prompt would work saying that you need to "enter a name" but for some reason now it doesn't is there another way of writing this code?

Also would anyone be able to point me in the direction of how to do a JPanel with a JTextArea that When a button is pressed, the text area will display "name" is hungry ? I have had a look around various things but cant get my head around it.
Thanks

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GuiEnvironment extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8573501273671847629L;
private JPanel firstPanel, labelPanel, wholeGUI, buttonPanel, textPanel, frog, fly;
private JButton newResetButton, newHungryButton, newPetButton;
private JTextField newName;
private JLabel state;
private Frog guiFrog;
private Fly guiFly;




public JPanel newEnvironment() {

    wholeGUI = new JPanel();
    wholeGUI.setLayout(null);


    // area for pet to chase upon 
    firstPanel = new JPanel();
    firstPanel.setLocation(20, 20);
    firstPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    firstPanel.setSize(550, 550);
    firstPanel.setLayout(null);
    wholeGUI.add(firstPanel);

    //panel for buttons
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    GridLayout newLayout = new GridLayout();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(newLayout);
    buttonPanel.setLocation(50, 575);
    buttonPanel.setSize(520, 50);
    wholeGUI.add(buttonPanel);

    //name button
    newName = new JFormattedTextField("");
    newName.setLocation(140,0);
    newName.setSize(50,30);
    buttonPanel.add(newName);

    //create pet button
    newPetButton = new JButton("Create Pet");
    newPetButton.setLocation (150, 0);
    newPetButton.setSize(50,30);
    newPetButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(newPetButton);

    // clear pet area
    newResetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    newResetButton.setLocation(420, 0);
    newResetButton.setSize(50, 30);
    newResetButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(newResetButton);

    // make pets hungry 
    newHungryButton = new JButton("Make Hungry");
    newHungryButton.setLocation(280, 0);
    newHungryButton.setSize(50, 30);
    newHungryButton.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(newHungryButton);

    //input panel
    textPanel = new JPanel();
    textPanel.setLayout(null);
    textPanel.setLocation(0, 550);
    textPanel.setSize(120, 120);
    firstPanel.add(textPanel);


    wholeGUI.setOpaque(true);

    return wholeGUI;
    }




private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=***] The Hungry Cyber Pet. [***=]");

    GuiEnvironment test = new GuiEnvironment();
    frame.setContentPane(test.newEnvironment());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if(e.getSource() == newPetButton && newName.getText().length() != 0){
        String name = newName.getText();
        guiFrog = new Frog(name);
        guiFrog.getDisplayArea(frog);
        guiFrog.getTextArea();
        firstPanel.add(guiFrog);
        guiFrog.start();
        guiFly = new Fly();
        guiFly.getDisplayArea(fly);
        firstPanel.add(guiFly);
        guiFrog.insertFly(guiFly);
        guiFly.start();
        firstPanel.revalidate();
        firstPanel.repaint();
    }

    if (e.getSource() == newPetButton && newName.getText().length()==0)
     {
        state.setText("You must enter a name");      
     }
    else if(e.getSource() == newResetButton){
        firstPanel.removeAll();
        firstPanel.revalidate();
        firstPanel.repaint();
    }

    else if(e.getSource() == newHungryButton){
        guiFrog.setHungry();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: This method as-is does not tell me anything, and you put one brace more before EOF. Please include whole code, including component definitions (crucial)

Comment: Ive updated with the entire class... Basically when you run the program you have to enter a name for the "pet" in  a text field i want a prompt to come up when it is blank saying enter name... it was working how it is now but all of a sudden decided it no longer likes it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using a JOptionPane as a prompt, then storing the value?

```
if (e.getSource() == newPetButton && newName.getText().length()==0)
 {
    String name =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(state, "You must enter a name");
    state.setText(name);      
 }
```

I don't do much with Swing, but I've used that before to get input from the user.

As for your other issue, maybe something like the code below would work for displaying text in a JTextArea when a JButton is pressed:

```
    // creates the JPanel that will hold JButton and JTextArea
    JPanel textAndButtonPanel = new JPanel();

    // the JButton the user will press to see if "name" is hungry
    JButton hungryButton = new JButton("Am I Hungry?");

    // the JTextArea that will initially be blank, but will display
    // "name" is hungry when the JButton is pressed
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);

    // sets up the event-handling for the JButton. When the button
    // is pressed, the JTextArea will display "name" is hungry.
    hungryButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textArea.setText(String.format("%s is hungry", name));
        }
    });

    // adds the JButton and JTextArea to the JPanel
    textAndButtonPanel.add(hungryButton);
    textAndButtonPanel.add(textArea);
```

Answer (score 3):

One of your main problems is that you're code is throwing a NullPointerException here:

```
state.setText("You must enter a name");
```

and you're not telling us this in your question.

This is caused by your not initializing the state JLabel variable. I'm guessing that it once was initialized (i.e., `state = new JLabel();`) somewhere, but for some reason you removed this code.  The solution is to initialize this variable, ... assign a new JLabel to it, and then add it to your GUI. Also in the future when you have questions and it's about an error or exception, please include all this pertinent information with your question.

Other unrelated issues, don't do this: `wholeGUI.setLayout(null);`. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one. Learn how to use the layout managers, and then use them fully.